# How to get rid of the repetitive commas of a R string

Tags: r

I have an R string looks like:

`0B5P4ZZ, 0B9P40Z, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,`

How can I get rid of the space-commas at the end of this string so that it looks like the following?

`0B5P4ZZ, 0B9P40Z`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution:

```
str_remove_all(s, "(, )+$")
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulS. Would this method work for a column of r data frame?

Comment: Yes, @KaihuaHou: `df <- data.frame(x = rep(s, 20)) ;

df %>% 
  mutate(x = str_remove_all(x, "(, )+$"))`.

Comment: In case, @KaihuaHou, the last character of each string is not a space but a comma, then use: `df <- data.frame(x = rep(s, 20))

df %>% 
  mutate(x = str_remove_all(x, "[, ]+$"))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
trimws(text, whitespace = '[, ]+')
[1] "0B5P4ZZ, 0B9P40Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stringr::str_replace('0B5P4ZZ, 0B9P40Z, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ', '(.*[A-Z]).*', '\\1')
[1] "0B5P4ZZ, 0B9P40Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you never expect to have any important text after repeated commas, you can just delete everything after ", ,":

```
> x <- "0B5P4ZZ, 0B9P40Z, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , "
> gsub(", ,.*","",x)
[1] "0B5P4ZZ, 0B9P40Z"
```

If you may have important values at the end of the string, you have to use more creative regex:

```
> x <- "0B5P4ZZ, 0B9P40Z, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 0B9P40Z"
> gsub("(, ){2,}",", ",x)
[1] "0B5P4ZZ, 0B9P40Z, 0B9P40Z"
```

`(, )` means match ", "; `{2,}` means only match `(, )` if you see it repeat at least twice consecutively.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add to the other great answers, this is a nice use case for a recursive function, though not particularly efficient.

```
get_rid_of_commas <- function(the_string) {
  
  if(substr(the_string, nchar(the_string) - 1, nchar(the_string)) == ', ')
    return(get_rid_of_commas(substr(the_string, 1, nchar(the_string) - 2 )))
  else
    return(the_string)
}

> get_rid_of_commas("0B5P4ZZ, 0B9P40Z, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ")      
[1] "0B5P4ZZ, 0B9P40Z"
```